# reloadRowsAtIndexPath messes up with animateWithDuration

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I tried to bond two actions at once. One of them changes the `heighForRow` dynamically the second one, stretches View.frame dynamically. Both are fired with same click. Problem is when I try to add `reloadRowsAtIndexPath`
After the touch, when row height changes, unfortunately the row titles and colors "mess up". For example, after the touch on place of 2nd row, the 1st row shows, on 3rd shows the 1st and so on with every click But changing the rowHeight works! And logs show that correct rows are touched - (so when I touch the 1st one, 1st one ist logged with NSLog). Any ideas?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil){

        cell = [[PrototypeCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
                [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
                [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
                [cell setIndentationWidth:0.0];

        PrototypeCell *prototypeCell =(PrototypeCell *)cell;
        prototypeCell.View = [[UIView alloc]init];
        prototypeCell.View.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 15, 120);
        prototypeCell.View.alpha = .5f;
        [cell addSubview:prototypeCell.View];
        DetailView *detailView = [[DetailView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 120, 320, 120)];
        [cell addSubview:detailView];
        prototypeCell.detailView = detailView;

        if (indexPath.row == 0){

                prototypeCell.View.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
                cell.textLabel.text = [self.thingList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            }
        if (indexPath.row == 1){

                    prototypeCell.View.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
                    cell.textLabel.text = [self.thingList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


            }
        if (indexPath.row == 2){
                    prototypeCell.View.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
                    cell.textLabel.text = [self.thingList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            }}

        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:21];
        cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:13];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        PrototypeCell *prototypeCell =(PrototypeCell *)cell;
        prototypeCell.detailView.hidden = !expanded[indexPath.row];

        return cell;

}


-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    int selectedRow = indexPath.row;
    NSLog(@"touch on row %d ", selectedRow);

    PrototypeCell *prototypeCell =(PrototypeCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    expanded[indexPath.row] = !expanded[indexPath.row];
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

   if (prototypeCell.stretched == NO){
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{

        prototypeCell.View.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 120);
    }
                     completion:nil];
                prototypeCell.stretched = YES;

    }

    else {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{

            prototypeCell.View.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 120);
    }
                     completion: nil];
            prototypeCell.stretched = NO;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is how you using the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier because it when the the cell is reused your following code won't execute .

```
if (indexPath.row == 0){

                prototypeCell.View.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
                cell.textLabel.text = [self.thingList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            }
        if (indexPath.row == 1){

                    prototypeCell.View.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
                    cell.textLabel.text = [self.thingList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


            }
        if (indexPath.row == 2){
                    prototypeCell.View.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
                    cell.textLabel.text = [self.thingList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            }
```

This code only executes when your cell is nil you have to move out this code out of the nil block if you wan't the reuse cell otherwise if you have limited cell and every cell will be different don't reuse .

Also move these two lines at the end after you finish your animations

```
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: Still does not do the trick unfortunately. The rows are still mixing. But I noticed some pattern - it is always the first one that jumps on another rows places.

Comment: Please see the updated answer you are not handling things correctly in cellforrow method

Comment: Ok, everything works, but I have to click twice to stretch/shrink frame on cell. I will play around with It a bit.